# Placing div right of tinymce textarea

Tags: html, css, tinymce, textarea

I'm trying to place a list of images right of a tinymce-textarea. 
It works fine with a plain textarea without tinymce, but when i add tinymce, the images are placed below it.

HTML:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="metadata">
  <div>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <img src="someimage.jpg">
    <img src="anotherimg.jpg">
    <img src="yetanotherone.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tiny_mce{
   display: block;
   width: 300px;
}

.metadata {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

edit: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twfya/5/

Comment: Add your working page url which has tinymce

Comment: @dinodsaurus that is content editor, which you can see in wordpress, any other blogs

Comment: @Sowmya Here's the jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/twfya/5/

Comment: @user570722 Check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the text-area with a div and make it display:inline-block

```
<div class="tinymc"> <textarea></textarea></div>

.tinymc{
    display:inline-block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twfya/8/)**

Comment: Thanks! But how can i align both blocks at the top?: http://jsfiddle.net/twfya/9/

Comment: @user570722 Add vertical-align:top to .metadata http://jsfiddle.net/twfya/11/ The top margin is coz of body margin specified in your css